# Using the Rails ApplicationHelper in Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, module, grape-api

I have a method defined in application_helper.rb:

```
def bayarea_cities
[
  ['San Francisco', 'San Francisco'],
  ['Berkeley', 'Berkeley'],
  ...
]
end
```

I'm also using Grape to create an API. It's in its own module outside the Rails app:

```
module FFREST
  class API_V2 < Grape::API
  ...
```

I'm pretty sure Grape is a Rack app, so it doesn't have normal access to the Rails modules. When I try to call the 'bayarea_cities' method in one of the API methods, I get an undefined variable or method error. I've tried include the ApplicationHelper module with 'include ApplicationHelper', but this did not work.

How can I get access to this inside the API class?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the update Deefour. I added `extend self` to my Helpers module, and referenced the methods as instance/mixin methods (not as module methods), but I'm still getting the same error. In my lib/helpers.rb file I have:

```
module Helpers
  extend self

  def bayarea_cities
    [
      'San Francisco',
      'Berkeley', 
      'Danville', 
      'Oakland',
      'Daly City', 
      'Sunnyvale'
    ]
  end 

  def us_states
    ['CA']
  end
end
```

and in my API file I have:

```
module FFREST
  class API_V1 < Grape::API
    include Helpers
    version 'v1', :using => :header, :vendor => 'feedingforward'
    ...
```

And of course, I have the config/initializers/helpers.rb file that says `require "helpers"`

But when I call the US states API method, for instance, by going to `http://localhost:5000/api/states`, I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `us_states' for #<Grape::Endpoint:0x007fd9d1ccf008>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create some `lib/helpers.rb` file with the contents: `module Helpers; end`
2. Move the `bayarea_cities` method into this module definition
3. Add a `config/initializers/helpers.rb` file containing `require "helpers"`
4. Inside the `ApplicationHelpers` class, add `include Helpers`
5. Inside your `API_V2` class add `include Helpers`

You'll now have told Rails to make the `Helpers` module available within your application, and made `bayarea_cities` available as a method within both your Grape API class and your Rails app. The above are steps simply to get the point across - you need to put this common functionality in a place it can be easily accessed by any part of your application. You can (and should) use namespace your `Helpers` module.

---

Another tip: add `extend self` to the module to avoid the need to define everything as class methods as you mentioned in the comment

```
module Helpers
  extend self

  def bayarea_cities
    #...
  end
end
```

Finally, if you're including the module properly with `include Helpers`, you *should* be able to acces the method simply as `bayarea_cities`, not `Helpers.bayarea_cities`. If this isn't the case, you should definitely show the error you get so we can sort that out for you.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I had to define the bayarea_ciites method as Helpers.bayarea_cities and call it as such as well.

Comment: Updated my answer with a bit more info to make things a bit cleaner (I hope).

Comment: Thanks for the update, Deefour. Still having an issue...please see the update I made to my original question.

Comment: I suggest reading through http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/ Unfortunately I don't know Grape well enough to provide more info. If Grape is executing code as class methods, you probably want to **`extend`** `Helpers` instead of `include` it. If you're using `include`, you don't need to use `extend self` in the module. Reading through the above article will likely give you the knowledge you need to sort things out. If not I suggest posting a new question to get the community's help.